# .env given at time of running the app shows undefined where as it works when given at time of creating the build

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have made a react app using `create-react-app` utility. I now create a production build using `npm run build` and I then upload it on my server

I then create a .env file and place variables like :
REACT_APP_DOMAIN="example.org"
REACT_APP_API_SERVER="https://example.org"

but the react app shows their value as undefined.

How can I solve this problem.

if I provide a .env file at time of running `npm run build` I am able to see the value of the variables.

I am using `serve -s build` to test this.

Comment: Make sure you restart the application after making changes to ur .env files

Comment: yes but still it does not take it. I was using serve -s build to deploy

Comment: @kevin : isn't that for npm start. I am using npm run build